# Editable DIV various browsers

Tags: html, css

I'm new at web designing and have there hard customer, im designing for her web page.
She was adding new posts through text area(it worked great), but there was a problem (like with every women)
She wanted something like "wysiwyg" during text adding and editing.
So i changed it to DIV with setted contenteditable.
Tested with Chrome - done
Tested with Firefox - done
Everything worked fine.
But then she came with her MAC with Safari...
Safari started to adding random
 `<div><br></div><div><p style="margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px Helvetica">`

Fonts everywhere Lucidas,Arials,Helveticas... Messing all divs that she touched.

Is there anything that can protect me from this? Something more advanced than iterating through text and deleting font markups?

Comment: First of all, I wouldn't go making comments about women like that, it's extremely disrespectful and won't lead people to want to help you that much. In spite of that, you would be wise to look into implementing a WYSIWYG text editor plugin that's already been built. If you're new to this, building one yourself will be a long and arduous task. Try something like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/), that would do what you're after

Comment: I think you're better off with something like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/), [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/), [Quill](http://quilljs.com/) or [whatever](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+text+editor+open+source). And teach her how to "paste as plain text" instead of just ctrl+v (or cmd+v), because that will paste styling as well (which you do NOT want).

Comment: I tried tinyMCE but it was wrong.Because her main problem was dangling letters in main page.For example "This word is too short to be at end of line must be on new line" So she need to see everything as it is as result on main page(I know various resolutions and it mess up, but as i say "hard customer") 
But @giorgio you may be right she copying from other editors,need to check this.

Comment: Never use hyphens to cut off words. It's not a newspaper. And what she is seeing might not be what someone else is seeing. It's just bad practice. And if she really wants to see it, then create a preview option so she can save whatever she's doing and edit it before publishing it.

Comment: This sounds more like an "RTF" problem than a "Mac" or "Safari" problem. did you even test in Chrome or FF with coped rich txt?

Comment: @BradAllred Yes now im 90% sure its "RTF" now she told me that she was copy pasting from different web pages. 
Chrome and Firefox have different issue they puting new lines in different forms.